# Why does jQuery slideToggle() function acts strangely for me in my table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm making a prototype in HTML and I want to make a table, which will display more table rows when a user clicks on a button. I want to use the `slideToggle` function or something smooth.

It works, showing the content, but there is some lag or something strange going on. I have applied somewhat the same function on other objects (not in tables) and there it have worked out nicely.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#show-more-rows').click(function() {
    $('#tr-button').slideToggle();
    $('.hidden-row').slideToggle();
  });
  $('#show-less-rows').click(function() {
    $('#tr-button').slideToggle();
    $('.hidden-row').slideToggle();
  });
);
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5SYBe/8/) for my table.

Any help and tips will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's slide animation doesn't support table rows. Just split up the table in two tables (the one visible and the one that will be expanded) and wrap the second one in a `div`. Now you can `slideToggle()` this `div`.

Here's your fix: http://jsfiddle.net/5SYBe/12/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate that you answered with a jsfiddle link. However, if you look at your jsfiddle, you can see in the table that the table data is not in line with the table above? How to fix this? =/

Comment: Since there are two tables now, each one requires definition about the column widths. So either you set fixed widths for both tables, or you determine the column widths dynamically with Javascript on expand (jQuery's width() will be handy). You may want to move the button within the gray container back as well.

Comment: Can you include the code in the answer itself rather than as a link to a jsFiddle?

Comment: The jsFiddle contains more than a few lines I changed in order to have it work. It's +wrapping div, -hidden trs, /moved buttons, /altering the onclick JS. It's illustrating the idea, not an ultimate fix.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using it on `tr` elements, which cannot be re-sized to less than their contents.. (*that is the way tables work*)

So the animation tries to animate their height from 0 to full but it fails so you see them at full size from the start.

The same goes on with the hiding. While the animation lasts (*which does nothing visually*) you see it and at the end where the elements gets hidden you get the final state..

Comment: Thank you and +1 for explanation.